# How git merge works for multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, multibranch-pipeline

I am setting up a multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins for my application. I am unsure about how different jenkinsfile checked into the repository handles merging.

For example, I have 3 branches, `master`, `develop` and `feature-1`, all those branches require a different pipeline configuration (see below).

`master`: 
1. build
2. test
3. deploy to PROD
4. tell everyone using email

`develop`:
1. build
2. test
3. deploy to DEV

`feature-1`:
1. build
2. test

From day 1, `master` has `Jenkinsfile` for production release, `develop` was branched with the same `Jenkinsfile` content, changes were made to deploy to DEV and removed last step, committed change.
Day 2: `feature-1` branched off `develop`, changes were made to remove deploy step and committed.

When `feature-1` is completed, we are merging `feature-1` into `develop` branch, since the commit that removed last step is dated after the develop commit, this is going to result in Auto-Merge and will make "develop" branch not deploy. Same will happen when `develop` is merged into `master`

Based on above potential issues, I think I must be doing something wrong here, what is the best practice for managing Jenkinsfile in Multi-branch pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement some flow control (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control) and maintain the same `Jenkinsfile` in all your branches.

`if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
    echo 'do all the things'
} else if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'){ 
    echo 'do a few things'
} else if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'feature-1'){ 
    echo 'do a couple things'
}`

The `BRANCH_NAME` information is exposed by Jenkins when using Multibranch Pipelines (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#additional-environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks! Is this the designed usage of multi-branch pipeline? If it is, how is this different from a static script (hard-coded within jenkin as a configuration code)

Comment: I would suppose yes that it is by design, it works for me at least. My slaves are Windows, RedHat, AIX and SunOS, maintaining a script would be a nightmare in my case but if it makes sense for you why not right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional statements like

```
// Note: this is a declarative pipeline 
stage('deploy PROD'){
when { branch 'master' } 
  steps {
    ...do deploy... 
  }

}
stage('deploy DEV'){
when { branch 'develop' } 
  steps {
    ...do deploy... 
  }

}
...
```

For more info see:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/declarative-examples/simple-examples/whenBranchMaster.groovy#L13
- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when